# Pushbullet + WebClient = download only body content from note notification

Tags: android, api, push-notification, webclient, pushbullet

This is my first attempt to use the **Pushbullet API** to read the latest notification sent.

I have successfully authenticated my `WebClient` and upload/download its last push, but I want to download only the body (note's message) from the push of `note type`. If you guys take a look at the example bellow, the `WebClient.DownloadString` brings not only the body, but also every information available from the push.

Is there a way to download only the note's message, and not everything from it?

```
wc.DownloadString("https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/pushes?limit=1");
```

Result:

> "{\"accounts\":[],\"blocks\":[],\"channels\":[],\"chats\":[],\"clients\":[],\"contacts\":[],\"devices\":[],\"grants\":[],\"pushes\":[{\"active\":true,\"iden\":\"ujCch9rXhnwsjAvxQ1EFi0\",\"created\":1.454030974949465e+09,\"modified\":1.454031099564189e+09,\"type\":\"note\",\"dismissed\":true,\"direction\":\"self\",\"sender_iden\":\"ujCch9rXhnw\",\"sender_email\":\"xx@gmail.com\",\"sender_email_normalized\":\"xx@gmail.com\",\"sender_name\":\"ABC\",\"receiver_iden\":\"ujCch9rXhnw\",\"receiver_email\":\"x@gmail.com\",\"receiver_email_normalized\":\"xx@gmail.com\",\"title\":\"abc\",**\"body\":\"test line 1\r\ntest line 2\r\ntest line
>   3\"**}],\"profiles\":[],\"subscriptions\":[],\"texts\":[],\"cursor\":\"eyJWZXJzaW9uIjoxLCJNb2RpZmllZEFmdGVyIjoiMDAwMS0wMS0wMVQwMDowMDowMFoiLCJNb2RpZmllZEJlZm9yZSI6IjIwMTYtMDEtMjlUMDE6MzE6MzkuNTY0MTg5WiJ9\"}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the API, no.  The easiest way is to parse the response with a JSON parser and get response["pushes"][0]["body"]